# Card element with shadow only on the bottom

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, android-compose-card

I am trying to create Card element and to add shadow only on bottom part with a little bit in left and right and zero on the top.

```
 Card(
    elevation = 10.dp,
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(color = seatfrogWhite, shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
        .graphicsLayer {
            this.shadowElevation = 10.dp.toPx()
            this.shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)
            this.clip = true
        }
        .height(50.dp)
        .width(100.dp),
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)
) {}
```

I have tried with `shadow()` modifier, but without success. It always add shadow on the top.

Comment: You can use the M3 [`ElevatedCard`](https://m3.material.io/components/cards/specs#a012d40d-7a5c-4b07-8740-491dec79d58b)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the M3 [`ElevatedCard`](https://m3.material.io/components/cards/specs#a012d40d-7a5c-4b07-8740-491dec79d58b):

```
ElevatedCard(
    Modifier.size(width = 180.dp, height = 50.dp),
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
    elevation = CardDefaults.elevatedCardElevation(8.dp),
    colors = CardDefaults.elevatedCardColors(containerColor = Teal200),
) {
    // Card content
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there way to create that in older sdk version before 33?